# Internal Linking to children in a list

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

Using fullPage.js (a jQuery scrolling menu), I have the following situation:

I have an unordered list - the source of which is an SQL database (using PHP to echo out).

There are only two items per page being echoed out.

At the top of the page, I have a simple Menu:

```
<a href="#theList:first-child">First Item</a>
<a href="#theList:last-child">Second Item.</A>
```

I want to link to the first and second items in the list.

Before the PHP, I have the following:

```
<a name="theList">
```

I have to set up  .. but how do I target the different children within the list?

Baffling me -- if anyone could help, I'd very very thankful!

Comment: You have '#theList' which refers to an id, which should be unique on a page.

Comment: I am confused about what you are even trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NathanRobb he's trying to use anchors for page content so when you click on them they will scroll there but he wants to select the first(and last) of the parent div.

Comment: @NathanRobb, Arthur is correct.  But the problem is there is only one <ul><li></li></ul> in the HTML as the PHP just repeats it.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to use fullPage.js should be:

1 .Have a menu with `data-menuanchor`:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li data-menuanchor="theList1"><a href="#theList1">First slide</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="theList2"><a href="#theList2">Second slide</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="theList3"><a href="#theList3">Third slide</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="theList4"><a href="#theList4">Fourth slide</a></li>
</ul>
```

2 .config with js: `anchors: ['theList1', 'theList2', 'theList3', 'theList4'],`

3 .add CSS rule to style

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
  anchors: ['theList1', 'theList2', 'theList3', 'theList4'],
  menu: '#menu',
  slidesNavigation: true
});
```

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
/* Reset CSS
 * --------------------------------------- */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,
form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a{
 text-decoration:none;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;    
}
fieldset,img {
    border: 0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
strong{
 font-weight: bold;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
caption,th {
    text-align: left;

}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#444;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border: 0;
}


/* Custom CSS
 * --------------------------------------- */
body{
 font-family: arial,helvetica;
 color: #333;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.wrap{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 960px;
 position: relative;
}
h1{
 font-size: 6em; 
}
p{
 font-size: 2em;
}
.intro p{
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
.section{
 text-align:center;
}
#menu li {
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #000;
 background:#fff;
 background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
            border-radius: 10px; 
}
#menu li.active{
 background:#666;
 background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
 color: #fff;
}
#menu li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #000;
}
#menu li.active a:hover{
 color: #000;
}
#menu li:hover{
 background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
#menu li a,
#menu li.active a{
 padding: 9px 18px;
 display:block;
}
#menu li.active a{
 color: #fff;
}
#menu{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 height: 40px;
 z-index: 70;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
}
.twitter-share-button{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99;
 right: 149px;
 top: 9px;
}
#download{
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 background-color: #49afcd;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from( #5bc0de),to( #2f96b4));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5bc0de', endColorstr='#2f96b4', GradientType=0);
 border-color: #2f96b4 #2f96b4 #1f6377;
 border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) rgba(0,0,0,.1) rgba(0,0,0,.25);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
#download a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff;
}
#download:hover{
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
 background-color: #2F96B4;
 background-position: 0 -15px;
 -webkit-transition: background-position .1s linear;
 -moz-transition: background-position .1s linear;
 -ms-transition: background-position .1s linear;
 -o-transition: background-position .1s linear;
 transition: background-position .1s linear;
}
#infoMenu{
 height: 20px;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 position:fixed;
 z-index:70;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 text-align:right;
 font-size:0.9em;
 padding:8px 0 8px 0;
}
#infoMenu ul{
 padding: 0 40px;
}
#infoMenu li a{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 22px 0 0; 
 color: #333;
}
#infoMenu li a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}
#infoMenu li{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
}
#examplesList{
 display:none;
 background: #282828;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 20px;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 29px;
 right: 0;
 width:638px;
 text-align:left;
}
#examplesList ul{
 padding:0;
}
#examplesList ul li{
 display:block;
 margin: 5px 0;
}
#examplesList ul li a{
 color: #BDBDBD;
 margin:0;
}
#examplesList ul li a:hover{
 color: #f2f2f2;
}
#examplesList .column{
 float: left;
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
#examplesList h3{
 color: #f2f2f2;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 margin: 0 0 15px 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}



/* Demos Menu
 * --------------------------------------- */
 #demosMenu{
 position:fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
 right:10px;
 z-index: 999;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li data-menuanchor="theList1"><a href="#theList1">First slide</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="theList2"><a href="#theList2">Second slide</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="theList3"><a href="#theList3">Third slide</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="theList4"><a href="#theList4">Fourth slide</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="section0">One</div>
  <div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="slide">Two 1</div>
    <div class="slide">Two 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">Three</div>
  <div class="section" id="section3">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not how fullpage.js works. You do not defined `id` for each section, but instead assign `data-anchor` values and use the `data-menuanchor` in the menu.

Comment: @Alvaro really, creator of the fullPage.js? I updated my code, please let me know if I'm using it right, thanks

Comment: Yeap, that's me. And yeah, much better now :) Although the CSS is up to him. He can also define the anchors using the `data-anchor` attribute instead of the  `anchor` fullPage.js option.